# Referencing a column from a subquery which is a column itself in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I try to reference a column in a sub-query which is a column itself in MySql but I got an error stating that the referenced column does not exists. It might be related to the way MySql executes sub-queries ...

```
SELECT 
    language AS 'SMS type', 
    year(ctime) AS 'Year', 
    monthname(ctime) AS 'Month',
    (SELECT count(1) 
     FROM sms_sent AS t2 
     LEFT JOIN history ON history_id =  history.id 
     WHERE language = `SMS type` 
     AND ctime <= date_sub(makedate(year(t1.ctime), month(t1.ctime)*30), interval 1 month) 
     GROUP BY language, monthname(ctime)) AS 'Previous month',
FROM sms_sent as t1
LEFT JOIN history ON history_id = history.id 
GROUP BY language, monthname(ctime)
```

Interestingly if I reference the column of the outer query Year as `Year` from the sub-query then it works ... the thing is that in the outer query I would like to use the monthname() function while in the sub-query the month() function ...

Comment: Mysql is not SQL-server

Comment: it is but probably you think it is not related to my question ...

Comment: No it isn't. SQL-Server = MSSQL!!

Comment: I know where are  you coming but believe me any RDBMS that supports SQL is an SQL server in itself. I'm fine if you use the SQL-Server tag for Microsoft SQL in this community

Comment: It would help if you would quote the error message instead of paraphrazing it. Also your subquery (`(...) AS 'Previous month'`) is only allowed to return a single value, so it will not work if your `group by` results in more than one row (you maybe meant to `join` with that subquery?). Also your `makedate`-formula looks suspicious (you should test it on some dates if it gives you the date you expect). Also you have an additional `,` before your `from`. So you might want to add: error message, example data, current and expected output.

Comment: this is the error message I got: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't1.ctime' in 'where clause'. You are right on your comments. I have just copy + pasted a small part of the entire SQL query and left the comma over there. The subquery will always return a single line based on the WHERE clause and the makedate returns the required result ... I have tested it as a separate query already

Comment: Please verify that this simplified query (with corrected comma) will give you this error. It is allowed to use `t1` inside the subquery (if it is a column of `sms_sent` of course), so you maybe have simplified your code too much, as I think otherwise it is at least technically correct (as long as your inner `group by` really only result in one row, which would btw mean that you don't need that inner `group by`). Be aware that this code will not run on MySQL 5.7+ with default options, because your `group by` does not match your `select`-list, but this would be a different error/problem.

Comment: Yes, the simplified version of this query is giving the error. Actually I'm using 5.0.95 (a pretty outdated version) of the MySQL server so probably that is the issue.

Comment: No, this should be valid in 5.0 too. Did you also verify the part "if it is a column of `sms_sent` of course"? My best guess is that `ctime` is a column of table `history`, and not of `sms_sent` (=`t1`).

Comment: yes, you are right. it is a column of history. So I can not reference a column from a left join in a sub query since the server evaluates the sub-query first and then the left join. Interestingly if i reference ctime on the column list through a function (e.g. year or monthname) and then give it an alias then I can use this alias in the sub-query.

Comment: I just moved the LEFT JOIN into a WHERE clause and now I can reference the ctime column inside the sub-query. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Of course you can use a column from a `left join`. But you gave the table `sms_sent` the alias `t1`. So if you use `t1.ctime` in your inner query (or also your outer query), it means `sms_sent.ctime`. And that column doesn't exist (in `sms_sent`), which is what your error message is saying. If you want to reference the outer `history.ctime` in the inner query, give the outer `history`-table an alias, e.g. `h1`, and use `h1.ctime` in your inner query.

Comment: typical overlooking kind of issue ... hands are quicker than eyes and at the end you do not understand what's happening :-) really appreciate all of your help and efforts to help me